# BIM 360 Regional Support via API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

A question has come up about BIM 360 cross regional support and what it means for people using the data management API.

We are using the BIM 360 data management API to integrate with our product.  Our customers will be creating their own Forge Apps and will register them with us. We are using https://developer.api.autodesk.com as the root URI for our requests. Will requests to the base URI be automatically routed to the correct region?

Answer (score 0):

The request URI does not need to change. The servers available for BIM 360 are US and EMEA regions. You can find out how to use the Model Derivative API and the Viewer API with the following post.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-docs-api-changes-access-data-european-data-center